# Integration in first order ODE?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I need help with the last step in the solution of this ODE
\begin{equation}
T'(t)-\lambda kT(t)=0. 
\end{equation}
The integrating factor is $e^{-\int_{0}^{t} \lambda k \mathrm{d}s}=e^{-\lambda k t} $ so 
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\Big (T(t)e^{-\lambda k t}\Big)=0.
\end{equation}
Integration over $(0,t)$ so
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{t}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}\Big(T(s)e^{-\lambda k s}\Big)\mathrm{d}t&=T(t)e^{-\lambda k t}-T(0)e^{-\lambda k 0}=0 \\
T(t)&=T(0)e^{\lambda k t}
\end{align}
How is the integral evaluated?

In the integral $T$ is now a function of $s$ but the integration variable is $t$, shouldn't it be
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{t}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}\Big(T(s)e^{-\lambda k s}\Big)\mathrm{d}t&=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}\Big(T(s)e^{-\lambda k s}\Big)\int_{0}^{t}\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}
T(s)e^{-\lambda k s}\Big [ t \Big ]^t_{0}\\
&=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}
T(s)e^{-\lambda k s}t \quad \text{?}
\end{align}

Comment: This is a typo, it should be $ds$ in the integral, not $dt$. You use the fundamental theorem of calculus which states that $\int_0^t F'(s) \, ds = F(t) - F(0)$.